# Bandcamp api: What POST info do you send, when querying the my_bands endpoint?

Tags: api

https://bandcamp.com/developer/account#my_bands
It doesnt say what youre sposta send, as POST, and if you send without a POST or empty array, you get a 'must be POST' error.  Their support isnt helping.

I have been able to use their other endpoints, so I know I've got the auth correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send an empty payload to https://bandcamp.com/api/account/1/my_bands, like:

```
var parameters = {
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+access_token }, 
  method: 'post',
  payload: '',
  muteHttpExceptions: true // we want to handle exceptions gracefully
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting, I'm not yet familiar with the Stackoverflow editor.